# Assign value to the same field of every element of non-scalar struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, field, assign

In Matlab, assigning cell arrays to a struct arrays field `foo` is possible with

```
my_array(1000).foo = [];
[my_array.foo] = some_cell{:};
```

Now what I would like to do is assign a single value to all fields in the array.  But whatever I tried, Matlab would return error messages instead of silently assuming that if I want to assign a single element of size `[1x1]`, it should be assigned to *all* fields.  I would be happy if I could simply say e.g.:

```
my_array.foo = pi;
??? Incorrect number of right hand side elements in dot name assignment.
Missing [] around left hand side is a likely cause.
```

So, how can I assign a single value to a field all over a struct array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) to solve this problem:

```
my_array(1000).foo = [];
[my_array.foo] =deal(pi);
```

However, note the square brackets in the second line with are necessary to temporarily convert the comma separated list `my_array.foo` into a vector.